# Eliminate gap between input text and button css, and put on same height

Tags: html, css

I tried looking at several other questions such as this and none of the answers seemed to help me (I must be doing something wrong).

Here is my form in HTML:

```
        <form id = "username_form">
            <input id = "username_entry" type = "text" name ="username" placeholder="Enter Username Here" />
            <input type ="button" value = "" onClick = save()>
        </form>
```

Here is the CSS I have related to the form elements:

```
input[type="text"]{
height: 50px;
width: 400px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
font-size: 250%;
background-color: #e60000;
border: none;
color:black;}

input[type="button"]{
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: #e60000;
border: none;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;}

#username_form{
position: relative;
top:40%;
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
left:20%;}
```

The issue I have currently is that there is a weird gap between the button and text elements and that they are not on the same line. Any help? Thanks and merry Christmas!

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top;` to button and write HTML inline https://jsfiddle.net/kbLjz5x3/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the `float` property to help?

```css
input[type="text"] {
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #e60000;
  border: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
input[type="button"] {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: none;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
#username_form {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<form id="username_form">
  <input id="username_entry" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username Here" />
  <input type="button" value="Save" onClick="save()">
</form>
```

Here is the same example on Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXjzYE

Comment: No problem, if this has helped, then it would be great if you could mark this as the accepted answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to the button to get rid of the gap between text box and the button and make them on the same line:

```
input[type="button"]{
position: absolute
}
```

And to make the text box and the button of the same height, change their "height" properties in CSS any way you want. For example this way:

```
input[type="text"]{
height: 48px
}
```